jpg diagram to latex
I want to obtain this jpg diagram as a latex code to modify the parameters


Please show us the TeX code you tried so far!

The only way is for someone who knows how to code in tikz to do it, since the program that can do this needs to recognize that they are nodes and identify the arrows, if you do it using the inkscape extension to convert image to Tex, which You will get a lot of lines and coordinates that when added together will give something similar, but do not expect the nodes, IDs and texts to appear, besides there is nothing complicated or challenging in the drawing and I assure you that there are thousands of similar examples from which to modify and get this.

You can make such diagrams using external vector drawing programs such as ipe, draw.io, etc. or using the native TikZ code. If you are not comfortable with writing TikZ code by hand, there are graphical tools for that as well. TikZiT is one such example. Here is a wikipedia list of many such tools.

+1. OP ask how to obtain the diagram as LaTeX code. This perfectly answers how to do that. -so there is absolutely no reason to downvote.
